# Why my index == "string" is not working in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with an equal statement in Javascript. Look at this screenshot:

[image]

I am trying to check whether index is the same as "Delete", but it is never true. It also is not true if I try `index === "Delete"` or `index == "Delete"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`index` is an Object, which does not appear to have a `toString()` method. Therefore calling `toString()` in it will most likely result in `[object Object]`, which is obviously not what you're after.

Try `if( index.return === "Delete")` instead.